# Prove that if $\lambda_j$ are the eigen values of $Df(\bar x)$, and if $\lambda_j<1$, then $\bar x$ is assymptotically stable.

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

We study the discrete dynamical system in $\mathbb{R^n}$ with differentiable function $f(x)$: 
$$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$
$1.$ Assume that $\bar x$ is a fixed point and consider small perturbations around $\bar x$ and define $x_n:=\bar x+y_n$ where $y_n$ is small.Derive the inearization of the above equation for $y_n$.

$2.$ Prove that if $\lambda_j$ are the eigen values of $Df(\bar x)$, and if $\lambda_j<1$, then $\bar x$ is assymptotically stable.

My Problem: I know only definations of stability,fixed point,jacobian but I do not know how to solve these.Please help me I need hints,I will follow them or give me some sketch of solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at $$x_{n+1}-\bar x=f(x_n) -f(\bar x) = Df_{\bar x}(x_n-\bar x)+o(x_n-\bar x). 
$$Let $A$ be the matrix $Df_{\bar x}$. You obtain a linearised system

$$y_{n+1}=Ay_n,$$which you will study by considering the eigenvalues of $A$. And then you will be able to conclude on the behavior of $x_n$.

If you need help with the above steps, ask in comments.

Comment: Thank you.From this I got part 1.But I need some more help for 2nd part.

Comment: @Flip THe easiest way for the stability for $y_n$, use the Jordan decomposition of the matrix $A$ and look at the beahviour of its powers.

Comment: sorry can you please tell me what will be $A=Df(\bar x)$?

Comment: @Flip the differential (in other words, the gradient) of the function $f$ at the point $\bar x$.

Comment: I know that it is derivative of $f(x)$ at $\bar x$, but how we can find this? f is general function so I am confused how to compute it.

Comment: If $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \begin{pmatrix}f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\\\vdots\\f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\end{pmatrix}$, then $Df(x) = \begin{pmatrix}\partial_{x_1}f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\partial_{x_2}f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\dots&\partial_{x_n}f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\\partial_{x_1}f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\partial_{x_2}f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\dots&\partial_{x_n}f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $f(x_n)=f(0,0,0,...,0,x_n)$ Is this correct?Then we will have first n-1 columns all 0